# detecting variable type in zend router variables

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, url

so I'm using zend_router to route my index page in my controller to an action other than the index action:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                         '/controller/:page',
                          array(
                              'action' => 'not-index',
                              'controller' => 'controller',
                              'page' => 1,
                              ),
         );
```

And the reason why I'm adding :page into the path is because there's pagination in that index and I'd like to have paginator to work even if the user only enters '/controller' into the browser, so it's got to be there (see: http://www.joewebster.co.uk/articles/zend-framework/7-zend-pagination-and-zend-router)...

the problem is....now other actions within the controller will redirect to that page as well and not to the proper action

so suppose I enter '/controller/other-action' to the browser, it goes to 'controller/not-index' with page = other-action instead of 'controller/other-action' due to that routing definition....is there a way to limit the :page in that router definition to integers only, ie. if I enter '/controller/2' then go to 'controller/not-index' with page = 2, and if I enter '/controller/other-action' it'll actually go to 'controller/other-action'

Comment: For `page` param to validated to integer, you must must a third array param to your route: `array('page' => '^\d+$')`. Also, the closest you can get with Router_Route is to change the route string to `/controller/:action/:page`, but still, `controller/2` won't work as expected. You need regex for that, as @maraspin said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at the Regex_router:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex

That should help you achieving your goal. I'm afraid the standard Router isn't flexible enough.